# Count distinct text contain in columns which have various texts - Mysql

Tags: mysql, distinct

I have a table:

| Rank | Title | Genre |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Guardians of the Galaxy | Action,Adventure,Sci-Fi |
| 2 | Prometheus | Adventure,Mystery,Sci-Fi |
| 3 | Split | Horror,Thriller |
| 4 | Sing | Animation,Comedy,Family |
| 5 | Suicide Squad | Action,Adventure,Fantasy |

Is there any function that I can count how many distinct text contain in theses columns？ And how many columns contain each text?
I am using MYSQL

Like

| Total distinct text |
| --- |
| 10 |

And

| **Adventure** | **Sci-Fi** | **Mystery** | **Horror** | **Thriller** | **Animation** | **Family** | **Comedy** | **Fantasy** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

Comment: Normally you would have a second table with only the `Genre` and a third table which will then link a movie to a genre (n:m relation). Then you could solve your with a `JOIN`. With this structure, it's not that easy to do this only in sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Split comma separated string into rows concatenate square brackets ([]) around your string to make it into a JSON array. Then use JSON_TABLE to convert it into a table.

To count distinct text use this query :

```
with cte as (
  SELECT t.Rank_, j.genre
  FROM mytable t
  CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(
                       CONCAT('["', REPLACE(Genre, ',', '","'), '"]'),
                      '$[*]' COLUMNS (genre TEXT PATH '$')
                      ) j
)
select count(distinct genre) as 'Total distinct text'
from cte
```

To count per genre :

```
    with cte as (
      SELECT t.Rank_, j.genre
      FROM mytable t
      CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(
                           CONCAT('["', REPLACE(Genre, ',', '","'), '"]'),
                          '$[*]' COLUMNS (genre TEXT PATH '$')
                          ) j
    )
    select genre, count(1) as 'count'
    from cte
    group by genre
```

You can use the conditional aggregation to Pivot rows into columns :

```
with cte as (
  SELECT t.Rank_, j.genre
  FROM mytable t
  CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(
                       CONCAT('["', REPLACE(Genre, ',', '","'), '"]'),
                      '$[*]' COLUMNS (genre TEXT PATH '$')
                      ) j
),
cte2 as (
       select count(case when genre = 'Action' then 1 end) as 'Action',
              count(case when genre = 'Adventure' then 1 end) as 'Adventure',
              count(case when genre = 'Sci-Fi' then 1 end) as 'Sci-Fi'
       from cte
       group by genre
)
select max(Action) AS 'Action', max(Adventure) as 'Adventure', max(`Sci-Fi`) as 'Sci-Fi'
from cte2
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/7IjFKt46)